# Allow Docker Apache write permissions to local synced volume

Tags: apache, docker

When running a Docker container, what is the correct way allow Apache write access to a synced volume?

- Important, I would like the folder synced so local changes are immediately reflected inside the container as is happening now with the current run command

When running the container with:
`docker run -v /Local/folder/toSync:/var/www/html -p 8080:80 --sig-proxy=false the-image`

The Docker Apache process does not have write access to the folder because the owner and group of that folder is set to `1000 staff` Where I believe `1000` is replacing my local username (which is absent from the container). Apache is running as `www-data` and therefore cannot write to the file.

Attempting to set the local folder user/group to `www-data` results in `chown: www-data: illegal user name`

What is the correct way to set permissions and/or mount the volume to permit Apache write access?

Comment: I would venture a guess that running Apache as user `1000` might do the trick, but this seems incorrect

Comment: What command are you running to set the local folder user:group to www-data?

Comment: `chown -R www-data folder`

Comment: Try specifying the group too? chown www-data:www-data file.txt

Comment: Same result, I dont have a `www-data` user locally. If need be I can create one, but is this the correct way to go about this? Seems like a rather common use case here

Comment: I don't think creating the user is necessary, are you using a dockerfile?

I would try adding this to the dockerfile:

`RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data`
`RUN usermod -G staff www-data`

Comment: Also assuming a newly created `www-data` user on my laptop would have a different `UID` and cause problems?

Comment: Giving the RUN cmd a try. Although, I believe that 1000 user doesnt get created until the folder is synced via the `run` command i use to start the container

Comment: `The command '/bin/sh -c usermod -u 1000 www-data RUN usermod -G staff www-data' returned a non-zero code: 2`

Comment: That's the way I fixed mine before (using a Dockerfile) - anyway there's a large discussion about this over at https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7198 so your best bet is to go there and look for a solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the :z on the end of your volume.

```
-v /Local/folder/toSync:/var/www/html:z
```

Also, the syntax of your chown statement doesn't looks right.  Changing the owner of the volume should work fine, and you will still need to do this.

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN chown -R www-data html
```